# sFTP Encoding in Cleo VLTrader

Tags: encryption, encoding, openpgp, base64

I want to secure a zip file using Base64 OpenPGP encryption. some application have the option in command line, I wonder if such feature is available in Cleo VLTrader's GUI?

Answer (score 0):

I did this via "Packaging" option in mailbox level.

Hosts -> Clients -> RemoteSFTP -> Mailbox -> Packaging = "OpenPGP" -> Configure -> Encrypt Outbound -> Armored (Base64)

Hope it helps.